# What is the difference between dl, dd, dt and ul li?

Tags: html, css

What is the difference and in which situations should each one be used?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it appears to be asking us to reproduce the HTML specification.

Comment: Do you remember when people used to google things ? Pepperidge farm remembers

Answer (score 22):

**UL:** *Unordered list, created with the UL element.*

**OL** *An ordered list, created using the OL element, should contain information where order should be emphasized, as in a recipe*

**DL** *Definition lists, created using the DL element, generally consist of a series of term/definition pairs (although definition lists may have other applications). Another application of DL, for example, is for marking up dialogues, with each DT naming a speaker, and each DD containing his or her words.*

Definition lists - **DT** for term, **DD** for its definition

**Definition lists** vary only slightly from other types of lists in that list items **consist of two parts**: `a term` and `a description`. The term is given by the `DT` element and is restricted to `inline` content. The `description` is given with a `DD` element that contains `block-level` content.

[Source](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/lists.html)

Comment: +1: beat me...would add some from my side too!! :)

Answer (score 1):

`<ul>` and `<li>` are for making an Unordered List, where every item doesn't have relationships.

`<dl>` is for making a Definition List, where you we can have a Definition Title inside `<dt>` and one or more definition description, for the above title, inside `<dd>` tags.

From [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/lists.html):

> HTML offers authors several mechanisms for specifying lists of information. All lists must contain one or more list elements. Lists may contain:
>
> - Unordered information.
> - Ordered information.
> - Definitions.
>
> The previous list, for example, is an **unordered list**, created with the **UL** element:
>   An **ordered list**, created using the **OL** element, should contain information where order should be emphasized, as in a recipe:
>   **Definition lists**, created using the **DL** element, generally consist of a series of term/definition pairs (although definition lists may have other applications). Thus, when advertising a product, one might use a definition list:

See these pages:

- [HTML `<ul>` tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_ul.asp)
- [HTML `<dl>` tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_dl.asp)
- [Lists in HTML documents - W3C source](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/lists.html)